# SQL JOIN between A, B and C mixing full and left join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, optimization

I'd like to know if there is a better way to create my left join in the below example:

```sql
SELECT TOP 10 COALESCE(A.COD_PRODUCT, B.COD_PRODUCT),
              COALESCE(A.COD_FAMILY, B.COD_FAMILY),
              COALESCE(A.DATE_EXTRACT, B.DATE_EXTRACT),
              A.MASS
              B.VOLUME
              C.PRICE
FROM FIRSTTABLE A FULL JOIN SECONDTABLE B ON B.COD_PRODUCT = A.COD_PRODUCT
                                          AND B.COD_FAMILY = A.COD_FAMILY
                                          AND B.DATE_EXTRACT = A.DATE_EXTRACT
LEFT JOIN THIRDTABLE C ON C.COD_PRODUCT = COALESCE(A.COD_PRODUCT,B.COD_PRODUCT)
                      AND C.COD_FAMILY = COALESCE(A.COD_FAMILY, B.COD_FAMILY)
                      AND C.DATE_EXTRACT = COALESCE(A.DATE_EXTRACT, B.DATE_EXTRACT)
```

That kind of jointure takes long time and I suspect it to be highly expensive and improvable

**EDIT:** I'd like to improve this `SELECT FROM JOIN` statement in a View.

Comment: You are already coalescing in your `SELECT` clause. I'd like to think that SQL Server is optimizing this so that it only does the `COALESCE()` once not really adding any significant increase in time to perform the third join, besides having to perform it in the first place. Perhaps toss everything but that third join into a subquery, then join outside of the subquery (After the SELECT `COALESCE()` occurs) to insure that SQL server only does that expensive operation once. Again though, it'll probably be a wash.

Comment: The COALESCE in the SELECT statement seems to be unnecessary given that you are joining on those same fields. Because you are joining when those fields match there will be no NULL fields to deal with, unless both tables have NULL.  For example if `B.COD_PRODUCT = A.COD_PRODUCT` equates to `NULL = NULL` then  there will be a row where COD_PRODUCT is NULL.  However the `COALESCE (A.COD_PRODUCT, B.COD_PRODUCT)` will still return `NULL`

Comment: When I do not use coalesce in the SELECT statement it changes a little bit. When using coalesce, 942028 lines where none of the 3 first column are null. If I don't use coalesce, 640142 lines when table A fields are used, 490522 lines when table B fields are used. So I will keep the coalesce.

Comment: It is not clear, you want to select `Top 10 of which table` or `Top 10 on order by of what column`.This is main criteria.

Answer (score 1):

You could split the query into two: gather all data matching FIRSTTABLE. And then union it with all data matching SECONDTABLE that is not in FIRSTTABLE.

That should allow SQL Server to use the indexes on these tables better.

```
SELECT A.COD_PRODUCT,
       A.COD_FAMILY,
       A.DATE_EXTRACT,
       A.MASS,
       B.VOLUME,
       C.PRICE
FROM FIRSTTABLE A
LEFT OUTER JOIN SECONDTABLE B
     ON B.COD_PRODUCT = A.COD_PRODUCT
     AND B.COD_FAMILY = A.COD_FAMILY
     AND B.DATE_EXTRACT = A.DATE_EXTRACT
LEFT OUTER JOIN THIRDTABLE C
     ON C.COD_PRODUCT = A.COD_PRODUCT
     AND C.COD_FAMILY = A.COD_FAMILY
     AND C.DATE_EXTRACT = A.DATE_EXTRACT
UNION ALL
SELECT B.COD_PRODUCT,
       B.COD_FAMILY,
       B.DATE_EXTRACT,
       NULL AS MASS,
       B.VOLUME,
       C.PRICE
FROM SECONDTABLE B
LEFT OUTER JOIN THIRDTABLE C
     ON C.COD_PRODUCT = B.COD_PRODUCT
     AND C.COD_FAMILY = B.COD_FAMILY
     AND C.DATE_EXTRACT = B.DATE_EXTRACT
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM   FIRSTTABLE A
                  WHERE  A.COD_PRODUCT = B.COD_PRODUCT
                  AND    A.COD_FAMILY = B.COD_FAMILY
                  AND    A.DATE_EXTRACT = B.DATE_EXTRACT)
```

Comment: This solution is straightforward and eliminates the COALESCE and possible temp tables.
Should be accepted as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the execution plan with this replacement join:

```
LEFT JOIN THIRDTABLE C
     ON (C.COD_PRODUCT = A.COD_PRODUCT or C.COD_PRODUCT = B.COD_PRODUCT)
     AND (C.COD_FAMILY = A.COD_FAMILY or C.COD_FAMILY = B.COD_FAMILY)
     AND (C.DATE_EXTRACT =A.DATE_EXTRACT or C.DATE_EXTRACT = B.DATE_EXTRACT)
```

Comment: Using coalesce in the jointure have a while cost of 25.64 while using the 'or' statements in the jointure have an estimated cost of 335 119. i think I will stay on my first try. A huge loop have 68% of the cost

Answer (score 0):

You might can achieve the same result with a UNION or UNION ALL

```
WITH cte AS (

    SELECT  
        A.COD_PRODUCT,
        A.COD_FAMILY,
        A.DATE_EXTRACT,
        A.MASS,
        NULL as VOLUME
    FROM
        FIRSTTABLE A
    UNION
    SELECT  
        B.COD_PRODUCT,
        B.COD_FAMILY,
        B.DATE_EXTRACT,
        NULL,
        B.VOLUME
    FROM
        FIRSTTABLE A
)
SELECT  
    *
FROM
    cte AB
LEFT JOIN 
    THIRDTABLE C    ON C.COD_PRODUCT = AB.COD_PRODUCT
        AND C.COD_FAMILY = AB.COD_FAMILY
        AND C.DATE_EXTRACT = AB.DATE_EXTRACT
```

If you can have Mass and Volume for the product,family,extract combination you can use aggregate to join A and B together

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        COD_PRODUCT,
        COD_FAMILY,
        DATE_EXTRACT,
        MAX(MASS) MASS,
        MAX(VOLUME) VOLUME
    FROM (
        SELECT  
            A.COD_PRODUCT,
            A.COD_FAMILY,
            A.DATE_EXTRACT,
            A.MASS,
            NULL as VOLUME
        FROM
            FIRSTTABLE A
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  
            B.COD_PRODUCT,
            B.COD_FAMILY,
            B.DATE_EXTRACT,
            NULL,
            B.VOLUME
        FROM
            FIRSTTABLE A
        ) T
    GROUP BY
        COD_PRODUCT,
        COD_FAMILY,
        DATE_EXTRACT
)
SELECT  
    *
FROM
    cte AB
LEFT JOIN 
    THIRDTABLE C    ON C.COD_PRODUCT = AB.COD_PRODUCT
        AND C.COD_FAMILY = AB.COD_FAMILY
        AND C.DATE_EXTRACT = AB.DATE_EXTRACT
```

Comment: Matches will no longer favour FIRSTTABLE in results so results may differ on FIRSTTABLE/SECONDTABLE matches. Also, there will be two rows returned on matches instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
--- isolate the full join data from a and b into a temp table
SELECT 
    COD_PRODUCT=    COALESCE(A.COD_PRODUCT, B.COD_PRODUCT),
    COD_FAMILY=     COALESCE(A.COD_FAMILY, B.COD_FAMILY),
    DATE_EXTRACT=   COALESCE(A.DATE_EXTRACT, B.DATE_EXTRACT),
    MASS=           A.MASS,
    VOLUME=         B.VOLUME
INTO #TEMP
FROM FIRSTTABLE A
FULL JOIN SECONDTABLE B
     ON B.COD_PRODUCT = A.COD_PRODUCT
     AND B.COD_FAMILY = A.COD_FAMILY
     AND B.DATE_EXTRACT = A.DATE_EXTRACT
-- add index clustered onto table (covering index)
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX ix_tempCIndex ON #Temp ([COD_PRODUCT],[COD_FAMILY],[DATE_EXTRACT],[MASS],[VOLUME]);

-- left join C to this temp table
SELECT TOP 10
    T.*, C.PRICE
FROM #TEMP T
LEFT JOIN THIRDTABLE C
     ON C.COD_PRODUCT = T.COD_PRODUCT
     AND C.COD_FAMILY = T.COD_FAMILY
     AND C.DATE_EXTRACT = T.DATE_EXTRACT
-- drop temp table
DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

Answer (score 0):

A coalesce or an OR inside of a join is going to slow down the query a lot. Depending on the size of the table, a better answer might be to join to table c twice. Once on table a and again on table B, then coalesce inside of your select clause.

SELECT TOP 10 COALESCE(A.COD_PRODUCT, B.COD_PRODUCT,c.COD_PRODUCT,ca.COD_PRODUCT),
COALESCE(A.COD_FAMILY, B.COD_FAMILY,c.COD_FAMILY,ca.COD_FAMILY),
COALESCE(A.DATE_EXTRACT, B.DATE_EXTRACT,c.DATE_EXTRACT,ca.DATE_EXTRACT),
A.MASS
B.VOLUME
C.PRICE
FROM FIRSTTABLE A
FULL JOIN SECONDTABLE B
ON B.COD_PRODUCT = A.COD_PRODUCT
AND B.COD_FAMILY = A.COD_FAMILY
AND B.DATE_EXTRACT = A.DATE_EXTRACT
LEFT JOIN THIRDTABLE C
ON C.COD_PRODUCT = A.COD_PRODUCT
AND C.COD_FAMILY = A.COD_FAMILY
AND C.DATE_EXTRACT = A.DATE_EXTRACT
LEFT JOIN THIRDTABLE Ca
ON Ca.COD_PRODUCT = b.COD_PRODUCT
AND Ca.COD_FAMILY = b.COD_FAMILY
AND Ca.DATE_EXTRACT = b.DATE_EXTRACT

Comment: WHAT'S WITH THE CAPS MAN ;~)